# Using Reactive MySQL Databases in Meteor (An Update?)

Tags: mysql, sql, meteor

I'm developing a new app and while I really like the entire Meteor ecosystem, I'm a bit turned off by the MongoDB requirements, mostly because a document-based database seems like putting a square peg through a round hole, due to the lack of Joins, which my DB setup would have used extensively.

It seems as if I'll need to "denormalize" my database and have lots of duplicate data if I choose to use MongoDB, and I haven't seen a convenient way to update the duplicated data if it needs to later be modified.

Now, I really want Meteor's offline DB capabilities and syncing for realtime updates, but it seems like my data better fits a classic relational database.

So, looking around, I saw that [Meteor had SQL support in its roadmap](http://roadmap.meteor.com), and that some [connectors](https://github.com/numtel/meteor-mysql) have been [written](https://github.com/drorm/meteor-sql) already, but I didn't see anything newer than early 2014 even discussing it, so does anyone know where SQL support is at in Meteor? Is there a recommended project that adds it, or an alpha in place?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to play Meteor with mySQL you will ended up using the [numtel/meteor-mysql package](https://github.com/numtel/meteor-mysql/).

There is a really [good example using mysql with the leaderboard example](https://github.com/numtel/meteor-mysql-leaderboard).

Take a look into the [documentation here](https://github.com/numtel/meteor-mysql/)

If you take a look into the comments on the [trello sql support board](https://trello.com/c/Gf6YxFp2/42-sql-support) Slava(core developer) point into the numtel package.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that a core developer seems to have accepted that package as a starting point. I believe that means it must be reasonable enough to implement and I'd guess the syntax won't change much once it's officially added. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, there are 3 ways to achieve this:

1.- Use SQL Sintax in client side: Get rid of minimongo limitations on grouping and unions. Use Alasql on the client and normalize mongo collections.

2.- Use a SQL Connector: Try numltel's MySql and PG connectors, or meteor-stream PG connector. The disadvantage is that they break deployments to meteor.

3.- Use mongo as a slave for relational database, keeping them in synch. MySql Shadow uses this. Also you might want to look at symmetric.ds to set mongo bidirectional replication with a lot of Sql engines.

I have collected my research in this repo:

https://github.com/vchigne/sqlAndMeteor

Comment: There was also a PostreSQL package recently released from an official repo:
https://github.com/meteor-stream/meteor-postgres

Comment: @Eckster Yes, it's mentioned in my repo along with numtel's  one.